# Microsoft Azure 記事の 「HDInsight での Hadoop ジョブの送信」の項目13がうまくいかない

Tags: azure

Microsoft の公式リファレンスを参考に作成したプログラムが正常に動作しません。

基本的には、 Microsoft Azure ドキュメントの 「[HDInsight での Hadoop ジョブの送信](http://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/hdinsight-submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/)」を参考にして作成しました。

毎回以下の `JobCreationResults jobResults = jobClient.CreateHiveJob(hiveJobDefinition);` で終了してしまいうまくいきません。

13. `Main()` 関数の最後に次のコードをコピーして、ジョブを実行し、ジョブの完了を待ちます。

    ```
    // Submit the Hive job
    var jobClient = JobSubmissionClientFactory.Connect(creds);
    JobCreationResults jobResults = jobClient.CreateHiveJob(hiveJobDefinition);

    // Wait for the job to complete
    WaitForJobCompletion(jobResults, jobClient);
    ```

ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: エラーやデータ、自分で設定した環境情報など、他に回答者が参考にできる補足情報はありませんか？ 他の人に考えてもらうには、情報が少なすぎるように感じます。

Comment: エラーとしては特に何も表示されず、JobCreation...の行にて動きがストップします。(無限ループ突入？)

自分で設定した環境としては、
「subscriptionID」：自分のサブスクリプションのIDを入力(Azureポータルで確認済)
「clusterName」：自作クラスターの名前を入力(Azureポータルで確認済)
「certFriendlyName」：自己署名証明書を発行し、そのフレンド名を入力(Azureポータルで確認済)
です。

それ以外はマニュアル通り動作させております。

自己署名証明書に関してはPowerShellを使うやり方及びIISを使うやり方の両方を試しています。

具体的には以下の条件で動作させております。

            string subscriptionID = "d0065947-1d79-4388-97aa-0efc2d51db91";
            string clusterName = "hiroyoshicluster";
            string certFriendlyName = "friendName";


どうぞよろしくお願いします。